# How to use declaration tag in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have one method and i took one variable int b=10 & i want to print this value
in display method. How can i do it ?

```
<%!
int b=10;
public void display()
{
    out.print(b);
}
%>
```

But it is giving error like, "Out cannot be resolved".

Comment: well where is 'out' declared about ? declare it within this current scriplet (although scriplets are bad practice, insecure and outdated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scriptlets are executed inside `service` method and each time this method is invoked to handle some request it needs to create its own set of *local variables* to not collide with other invocations of `service` method which will handle different request. One of this local variables is `out`.

Since `<%! ... %>` is responsible for declaring code at class-level it doesn't have access to local variables of `service` method.

If you really need to have access to `out` you can pass it to `display` method as argument like

```
public void display(JspWriter out) //javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter 
{
    out.print(b);
}
```

You could also create other method, which instead of being responsible for displaying, will return content to display like

```
public int getB()
{
    return b;
}
```

You can use it in scriptlet with `out` like `<% out.print(getB()); %>` or `<%=getB()%>`

## But [you should avoid scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 0):

A scriptlet is introduced with <%, not <%!.  Additionally, there is a bit of information missing.  Is this running within a JSP file within a server like, for example, Tomcat?

The "out" variable should be defined as it is a standard predefined variable in a JSP.

Comment: `out` is defined if you're in `<% %>` but not when in `<%! %>`...And yes, there is such a thing as `<%! %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever placed inside a declaration tags gets initialized during JSP initialization phase. So the implicit object "out" is not yet available here.

If you really need to output something within your own method (in the jsp class) you can do like that:

```
<%!
int b=10;
public void display(HttpServletResponse res) {
    try {
        res.getWriter().write(b) ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
%>
```

and later in the jsp:

```
<%= display(response) %>
```

Comment: Exception occuring hab:

Comment: Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /NewFile.jsp
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)